# Looking for a Bash loop command to rename a directory of files, inserting a whitespace before and after a dash

Tags: bash, loops, directory, whitespace

I have a directory with files such as:

```
01-artist name-song name 1.mp3
02-artist name-song name 2.mp3
03-artist name-song name 3.mp3
etc.
```

I am looking for a loop command to rename the files, so they become:

```
01 - artist name - song name 1.mp3
02 - artist name - song name 2.mp3
03 - artist name - song name 3.mp3
etc.
```

Essentially, I need a whitespace to be inserted before and after every dash.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain `bash`, a single `for` loop would do the job:

```
for file in ./*-*.mp3; do mv "$file" "${file//-/ - }"; done
```

With `${file//-/ - }`, all instances of `-` in the expansion of the parameter `file` are replaced with  `-` . Note that the snippet above will insert spaces around the `-`, even if it already has. If that isn't desirable, the code below can be used.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
for file in ./*-*.mp3; do
    newname=${file//-/ - }
    newname=${newname//+([[:blank:]])/ }
    [[ $file != "$newname" ]] && mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${newname//+([[:blank:]])/ }` is used to squeeze blanks. This requires `extglob` option to be set.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename` command:

```
rename -n 's/-/ - /g' *.mp3
```

Output:

```
rename(01-artist name-song name 1.mp3, 01 - artist name - song name 1.mp3)
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.